# WP OnePress custom font

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, webfonts

I am trying to set "not included" font to OnePress template. I tried plugins and etc. but it doesn't work. Same with CSS. For example, I used this:

```
     @import url("https://use.typekit.net/zni3ajm.css");

    body, body p { 
        font-family: century-gothic,    sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
     } 
     #page .site-branding .site-title, #page .site-branding .site-text-logo { 
        font-family: century-gothic,    sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
     } 
     #page .site-branding .site-description { 
        font-family: century-gothic,    sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
     } 
     .onepress-menu a { 
        font-family: century-gothic,    sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
     } 
     .hero__content .hero-large-text, .hero__content .hcl2-content h1, .hero__content .hcl2-content h2, .hero__content .hcl2-content h3 { 
        font-family: century-gothic,    sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
     } 
     body h1, body h2, body h3, body h4, body h5, body h6,
        .entry-header .entry-title,
        body .section-title-area .section-title, body .section-title-area .section-subtitle, body .hero-content-style1 h2 { 
        font-family: century-gothic,    sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
     }
```

But it changes only the navbar text, nothing else.

Weirdest part is: https://ctrlv.cz/VnU7
It works if I put in that CSS edit. But then I click publish, and on the original page is only navbar updated. Can someone help me?

Btw, I am importing from adobe creative cloud.

EDIT: I tried a different font and it works! How is it possible? Can I fix it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use @font-face and import the font directly on your style file**

For example

```
@font-face {
font-family:"century-gothic";
src:url("https://use.typekit.net/af/afc5c6/00000000000000003b9b1f23/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3") format("woff2"),url("https://use.typekit.net/af/afc5c6/00000000000000003b9b1f23/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3") format("woff"),url("https://use.typekit.net/af/afc5c6/00000000000000003b9b1f23/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3") format("opentype");
font-display:auto;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;
}
```

Then use it on you code:

```
body, body p { 
        font-family: century-gothic;
     }
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes!